# Is there an efficient way to run a sub-regex replace statement in a larger regex replace in php

Tags: php, regex

I am converting a handlebars template to be reusable within the compiled page.

Sample code:

```
{{title}} 
<div id="desktop">
    {{#each menu}}
        <a href="{{link}}">{{name}}</a>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

On the compiled page, I am wanting

```
Search Engines
<div id="desktop">
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
    <script type="text/template" id="repeatable-menu"><!--
        <a href="{{link}}">{{name}}</a>
    --></script>
</div>
```

I am able to get halfway there by doing a regex replace on the template before it is compiled by handlebars and get the output

```
Search Engines
<div id="desktop">
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
    <script type="text/template" id="repeatable-menu"><!--
        <a href=""></a>
    --></script>
</div>
```

by using the regex statement:

```
$templateHTML = preg_replace('/({{#each (.*?)}}(.*?){{\\/each}})/s', '$1<script type="text/template" id="repeatable-$2"><!--$3--></script>', $templateHTML, -1);
```

Another alternative I have come up with is to break up the handlebars statements with something like this `<a href="{|{link}|}">{|{name}|}</a>` but I am unsure how to do that and preserve the {{title}} variable.

would it be the wisest to run this code in a while loop until no replacements are made?

```
$templateHTML = preg_replace('/(<script type="text\\/template" .*?\\><!--.*?){{(.*?--\\>\\<\\/script\\>)/s', '$1{|{$2', $templateHTML, -1, $count);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing it in a single preg_replace, you could use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to match the pattern for the template.

Then loop through the links in the callback function.

**Example snippet:**

```
<?php

$template = '{{title}} 
<div id="desktop">
    {{#each menu}}
        <a href="{{link}}">{{name}}</a>
    {{/each}}
</div>';

$links = array(
    "Google"=>"https://google.com", 
    "Yahoo"=>"https://yahoo.com"
);

$result = preg_replace_callback(
            '/^\s*\{\{#each\s*([^{}]*)\}\}\s*^(.*?)^\s*\{\{\/each\}\}/sm',
            function ($matches) {
                $eachloopscript = $matches[0];
                $eachlooptitle  = $matches[1];
                $eachlooplines  = $matches[2];

                $scripttext = '<script type="text/template" id="repeatable-'.$eachlooptitle.'">';

                global $links;
                foreach($links as $x_key => $x_value) {
                    $temp = str_replace('{{link}}',$x_key,$eachlooplines);
                    $scripttext .= str_replace('{{name}}',$x_value,$temp);
                }

                $scripttext .= '<!--'.$eachloopscript.'--></script>';

                return $scripttext;
            }, 
            $template);

echo '<xmp>'.$result.'</xmp>';
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was wanting! I didn't know that function existed! I see so much potential with it. Thank you!